# Blank screen when trying to install from USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, dell

I have a laptop Dell Inspiron 1545 with Windows Vista Home Basic. I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Vista for the first time.

1. First, I freed about 50GB from the hard drive to use with Ubuntu.
2. Then, I downloaded the file `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`, and `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.0.4`. I used the universal installer to prepare my 4GB HP pendrive to boot and install Ubuntu.

What I see inside the pendrive is this within a FAT32 filesystem:

[image]

I did this all from an user account that is not the admin account. I don't think this should be relevant but mention it just in case.

Finally, I restarted the computer, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and choose boot from USB drive.

Next, I saw was a black screen with a this sign "_" on the top left corner and the led on the pendrive looked active. I waited for about 15 minutes and it all remained the same. Not even an error message. I made all the downloading, etc. again from scratch and got the same results.

I followed the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM for Windows, installed winMD5Sum and made the comparison between the hashes on the md5sum file on the pendrive and the one that corresponds to `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` but they did not match.
Any help please?

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/71679

Answer (score 2):

It seemed to be a problem with the usb port or the pendrive. I finally burned the iso image on a dvd and made the install from there without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download your iso from? Normally you should get the same thing if you downloaded it straight off the Ubuntu site. Although your image seems to point out that you have the right files, although I have noticed you have some different ones to my USB installer, although I was installing from XP I don't think that should change much this is what I've got: [image]

I'm guessing you mounted it correctly but did you try mounting it with [Pendrivelinux?](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) For me that's what I've found has work best over the number of times I've had to install Ubuntu, never had an issue.

Comment: I first mounted it with pendrivelinux. Also tried with unetbootin. In both cases I mounted it with administrative privileges. Also, I checked the hash with winmd5sum and was ok. I keep having the same problem. Also reviewed all that was in damien link. Any other clues?

Comment: and I got the iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have a clue then, I'd try asking in the chat channel if any of the more experienced users knows how to fix this issue.